# How to write a strong number function in Java

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJKpL.png)I am trying to solve this question:

a) Write a method with the following header that takes an integer n and
returns the value of n! (pronounced n factorial) computed as follows:

```
public static int factorial(int n)
```

Note that 0! = 1 and n! = n * (n-1) * (n-2)*.....*1.
Example: factorial(4) will return 24 which is = 4*3*2*1.

b) Write a method with the following header that takes an integer x and
returns true if x is a Strong number. Otherwise, it returns false.

```
public static boolean isStrongNumber(int x)
```

Note that the `isStrongNumber` method should call the factorial method to compute the factorial of
each digit in x.

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    int f =1;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) 
       f=f*i;

    return f;
}
```

```
     public static boolean isStrongNumber(int x) {
        int temp = x;
        int z;
        int q = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (temp > 0) {

            x = x % 10;
            z = factorial(x);
            q += z;

            if (q == temp) {
                System.out.print(q + " ");
                return true;

            }
        }

    }
```

This is my answer, but I get an error every time I try to run it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not return boolean value at end of the `isStrongNumber` method

```
     public static int factorial(int n) {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result *= i;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isStrongNumber(int num) {
        int originalNum = num;
        int sum = 0;

        while (num > 0) {
            sum += factorial(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        return sum == originalNum;
    }
```

, `main` function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            if (isStrongNumber(i)) {
                set.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Strong numbers between 1 and " + number + " are:");
        System.out.println(set);
        scanner.close();
    }
```

, output for input `100000`

```
Enter a positive integer: 100000
The Strong numbers between 1 and 100000 are:
[1, 2, 145, 40585]
```

Comment: okay i tried your code but it's not displaying the numbers when i call the method in main. (I call it by typing isStrongNumber(a);)

Comment: yes, because you display only if it's true, I tried `145`

Comment: i need to display all the number for zero to a that are strong number. btw sorry i am new to programming it's my first year and all online session.

Comment: So you need to display `reminder` in every iteration, could you example what do you intend to do?

Comment: so i need to write a method to display all strong number for 0 to an integer that the user give in main method, in the  'isStrongNumber' method i should write all codes that make the calculations and display all number from o to the variable a that the user gives.

Comment: I don't know If I got you correctly I have updated the code

Comment: Okay, let me check that

Comment: thank you, I've been trying since yesterday and couldn't solve it. i appreciate it.

Comment: Could you approve the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

This cannot compile as it lacks a return statement outside the while loop. In fact, you cant be sure to go inside the loop even once if x<=0 for exmaple. You should add return false outside the loop at the end of the method. Also if you get an error and write a question on StackOverflow, copy the error message it's very helpful.